# WPF: Failing to Clear Items in List & To Add New Channels

Tags: c#, wpf, list, button, mvvm

I am developing an app in WPF where I should dynamically generate UI components and perform some operations on it. I have done this as follows:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}}">            
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="115" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ChannelName}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding VoltageText}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Set" CommandParameter="{Binding VoltageText}" Command="{Binding VoltageCommand}" />
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding CurrentText}"  />
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="3" Content="On" />
</Grid>

<Button Content="Bavaria" Name="BavariaBtn" Click="BavariaBtn_Click" />
```

**XAML.cs:**

```
public void OnChildAdd()
    {            
        foreach (VoltageBoardChannel mVoltageChannelViewModel in mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList)
        {
            VoltageChannelView mVoltageChannelView = new VoltageChannelView();
            mVoltageChannelView.Margin = new Thickness(2);
            mVoltageChannelView.ChannelInfo = mVoltageChannelViewModel;
            //Some Code to add the item
        }
    }

    private void BavariaBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VoltageViewModel mVoltageViewModel = new VoltageViewModel();

        // Here List should get cleared and Bavaria 2 items should be added
        mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList.Clear();
        mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList = mVoltageViewModel.bavaria2Channels;            
        OnChildAdd();
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public List<VoltageBoardChannel> channelList = null;        

    public List<VoltageBoardChannel> bavaria2Channels = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__IO__AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC__AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__DAL__AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__DPD__AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__PLL__AUD", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__AMP1__AUD", IsAvailable = true},
    };

    private ICommand m_voltageCommand;        

    public List<VoltageBoardChannel> bavaria1Channels = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>
    {
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__MAIN", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__IO", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__LDO", IsAvailable = true},
         new VoltageBoardChannel { ChannelName = "VDD__AMP", IsAvailable = true},  
    };            

    public VoltageViewModel()
    {
        channelList = new List<VoltageBoardChannel>(0);
        channelList = bavaria1Channels;            
        m_voltageCommand = new DelegateVoltageCommand(x => SetCommandExecute(x));            
    }

    public List<VoltageBoardChannel> VoltageChannelList
    {
        get 
        { 
            return channelList; 
        }

        set
        { 
            channelList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelList");
        }
    }
```

**Model Class:**

```
private string mChannelName;
    public string ChannelName
    {
        get
        {
            return mChannelName;
        }
        set
        {
            mChannelName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ChannelName");
        }
    }

    private bool mIsAvailable;
    public bool IsAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            return mIsAvailable;
        }
        set
        {
            mIsAvailable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsAvailable");
        }
    }        

    public ICommand VoltageCommand { get; set; }
```

You can notice in ViewModel class that Bavaria 1 is displayed on startup. What I basically want here is to clear the items and then display the Bavaria 2 items on `BavariaBtn_Click()` as shown in xaml.cs class. I am trying to do it but the list doesnt get cleared, although the items are getting added.

How can I achieve it? :)

Answer (score 1):

You're clearing a local variable. The XAML has no idea you've done this, and in fact nothing knows you have cleared the local variable but the method itself:

```
// Nobody knows the trouble I've seen...
VoltageViewModel mVoltageViewModel = new VoltageViewModel();

// Here List should get cleared and Bavaria 2 items should be added
mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList.Clear();
```

The MVVM approach to clearing the list would be to add a Clear command to your view model:

```
public ICommand ClearCommand { get; private set; }

// ...

public VoltageViewModel(...)
{
    // ...
    this.ClearCommand = new DelegateCommand(
        () => this.VoltageChannelList.Clear(),
        () => this.VoltageChannelList.Count > 0);
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<Button Content="Bavaria" x:Name="BavariaBtn" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
```

Comment: :Well I already have `BavariaBtn_Click()` in my .cs file and now if I use `Command` then don you think it will lead to ambiguity??? I tried it and on clicking the button nothing seems to happen. Since you are recommending clearcommand, how can we both clear the list and add a new channel?

Answer (score 0):

Simple List does not send notifications about the changes about its elements. It not implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

`ObservableCollecition` does, so 
use `ObservableCollection` instead of list for your **VoltageChannelList** property and you 
won't need the `OnPropertyChanged("VoltageChannelList");` in the setter

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it using `ObservableCollection<>` but still the list doesn't get cleared on Button click

Answer (score 0):

First... You do need to use an ObservableCollection. The list will not send notifications as @Miklos stated.

Secondly, when you do:

```
mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList = mVoltageViewModel.bavaria2Channels;
```

you are wiping out the VoltageChannelList list. You cannot do this. You will have to iterate over the list and copy the items in manually

```
private void BavariaBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   
    {   
        VoltageViewModel mVoltageViewModel = new VoltageViewModel();   

        // Here List should get cleared and Bavaria 2 items should be added   
        mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList.Clear();   

        foreach (VoltageBoardChannel channel in  mVoltageViewModel.bavaria2Channels) 
            mVoltageViewModel.VoltageChannelList.Add(channel);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but it still doesn't clear items nor adds new items.